# Regedit Don't open

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-registry, powershell-4.0

I modified Registry key **ProgramFilesDir** to install more applications in External HDD but after reboot I can't open any application installed in my Pc , or any utilities of windows like Regedit / RegINI  . when I try to change a value of registry key with **powershell** I can't because a permissions to access to registry ... So have you any other solution before to repaire it with windows installation !

Answer (score 0):

If your system is periodically creating restore points than just restore your system using restore point from date before you made changes in your registries. It should rollback changes you did after restore point. It is also recommended to backup your registry keys before change.

You can restore your system after boot or using option `Recovery` in `Control Panel`.